# Crystal Report Formula - Get numeric from alphanumeric characters

Tags: crystal-reports

I need a way to extract a numeric value from an alphanumeric one, for example :

```
3 MS 15 SEC
```

Desired:

```
3.15
```

Comment: can you give me some other examples  so can analysis properly

Comment: post what you have tried also..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Local NumberVar i;
Local StringVar k;


for i:=1 to Count (Split("3 MS 15 SEC"," ")) do
(
  if NumericText (Split("3 MS 15 SEC "," ")[i]) then (
    k:=k+Split("3 MS 15 SEC "," ")[i]+".";
  )
);

if k<>"" then 
  k[1 to length(k)-1] 
else 
  k //drop final "."
```

Comment: Would be a little more concise with `local stringvar array splitArry := split("3 MS 15 SEC");` That way you don't have to keep reusing the same split function call over and over.

Comment: @Ryan...its a good suggestion...thanks for making it more precise

Comment: You're approach returns a `stringvar`, not a `numbervar` as the OP requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// {@extract}
Local Stringvar Array tokens:=Split(x);
Local Stringvar Array values;
Local Numbervar i;

for i := 1 to uBound(tokens) do (

  if isNumeric(tokens[i]) then (
    redim preserve values[ubound(values)+1];
    values[ubound(values)]:=tokens[i];
  )

);

ToNumber( Join(values,".") );
```